# check condition after download

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a class in my activity that downloads an mp3 file and then returns some data. Before the download is completed it checks a condition. The download process is done in background.

I'd like to implement a condition check after the download is completed. Could you mention a way to do so?

**update**
     It works fine but after it finishes downloading                    resultFromDownload= getFromSdcard(); executes.
but after that I want it to return     this statement execute:

```
  return resultFromDownload;
```

but nothing happen after onPostExecute.

```
 private String downloadSomeFiles(String filename) {

 DownloadImage downloadimage = new DownloadImage();
 downloadimage.execute(filename);
  **return resultFromDownload;**
}
```

this AsyncTask:

```
private  class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    // This is run in a background thread
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        // get the string from params, which is an array

        Boolean resul = true;
        try{
            DownloadRequest downloadRequestLrc = new DownloadRequest()
                    .downloadPath("http://192.168.1.108/music+".mp3)
                    .filepath(G.DIR_APP + "/" + music+ ".mp3")
                    .simulate(true)
                    .download();
            downloadRequests =downloadRequestLrc;

        } catch (Exception e){
            resul=false;
        }

        return resul;
    }

    // This is called from background thread but runs in UI
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        // Do things like update the progress bar
    }

    // This runs in UI when background thread finishes
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
       if(result){
            // Log.i("resulyyyy : ",result);

            **resultFromDownload= getFromSdcard();**

            Log.i("result1 : ",resultFromDownload);

       } else {
            resultFromDownload="";
            Log.i("result2 : ",resultFromDownload);

       }


        // Do things like hide the progress bar or change a TextView
    }
}
```

Comment: You can put it in an `AsyncTask` and do what you need after it finishes in `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an `AsyncTask` class to do it as [`@codeMagic`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1380752/codemagic) said.

An example would be :

```
private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    // This is run in a background thread
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        // get the string from params, which is an array

        Boolean resul = true;
        try{
            DownloadRequest downloadRequestLrc = new DownloadRequest()
                    .downloadPath("http://192.168.1.108/music.mp3")
                    .filepath(G.DIR_APP + "/" + params[0] + ".mp3")
                    .simulate(true)
                    .download();
            downloadRequests =downloadRequestLrc;

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            resul=false;
        }

        return resul;
    }

    // This is called from background thread but runs in UI
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        // Do things like update the progress bar
    }

    // This runs in UI when background thread finishes
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result){
            //All allright
        }
        else{
            //Problem!
        }

        // Do things like hide the progress bar or change a TextView
    }
}
```

And the call would be :

```
DownloadImage downloadimage = new DownloadImage();
                                downloadimage.execute(filename));
```

Comment: what is result in onPostExecute?

Comment: Look at this image, it's clearly explained [AsyncTask](http://i.stack.imgur.com/I23KW.png)